# Creating SQL Columns from XML Attribute values

Tags: sql, xml

I'm hoping someone can advise or help. I have some XML from a client (terribly formatted, I have to say), and I’d like to extract some attributes from the XML element, create the value for that attribute as a column, and then populate that column with the respective value from node.
So, for example below, extracting the `nField` attribute value, and then assigning it the corresponding `<value>` to which it refers:

```
<root>
<entry dType="TXT" bMark="Name" nField="FName">
     <value>Johnny</value>
</entry>
<entry dType="TXT" bMark="Product" nField="ProdRng">
     <value>ABC</value>
</entry>
```

… etc

Resulting in a table having 2 columns, the first header being "`FName`" with Value `"Johnny"`, and the second header being "`ProdRng`" and its Value `"ABC"`.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: If you are doing some data integration stuff , you need data intgration tools like Pentaho, SSMA. They give you better vision of your data source , you can do it in your developping enviroment too but you need to analys your source very carefully.

Comment: First [edit] your question and tag it with the RDBMS you are using (SQL Server, or Oracle, or PostgreSQL, ...). Then remove the SQL tag as the answers will likely not be ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SQL Server; a solution by using dynamic SQL is:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @txt nvarchar(max) = 
'<root>
<entry dType="TXT" bMark="Name" nField="FName">
     <value>Johnny</value>
</entry>
<entry dType="TXT" bMark="Product" nField="ProdRng">
     <value>ABC</value>
</entry>
</root>';

with t as (
    select cast(@txt as xml) as x
), columnsInfo as (
    select 
        tx.c.value('@nField', 'nvarchar(20)') columnName,
        tx.c.value('@dType', 'nvarchar(20)') columnType,
        tx.c.value('./value[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') columnValue
    from t
    cross apply t.x.nodes('/root/entry') tx(c)
)
select 
    @sql = 
        case when @sql is null then 
            'create table [t' + cast(newid() as nvarchar(40)) + '] ('
            -- I use `newid()` for name of table to avoid duplicate
        else 
            @sql + ','
        end + ' [' + columnName + '] ' +
        case when columnType = 'TXT' then
            'nvarchar(255)'
        else
            '[int]'
        end +
        ' null'
from columnsInfo;

set @sql = @sql + ') on [primary]';

exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
```

SQL command will be:

```
create table [t3C34CC17-CE06-483E-960E-F8C5E31478AE] ( [FName] nvarchar(255) null, [ProdRng] nvarchar(255) null) on [primary]
```

[**`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5023)